# How do I get Facebook Open graph / social (like box) to work correctly on my site?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I thought I had everything set up correctly with my open graph / facebook app settings on my [site](http://noahsdad.com/), but it looks like there are still problems. I just ran my site through the [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://noahsdad.com/) and here is what I'm getting. I can't figure out what is causing these errors.

```
/* ------------------------- Actions --------------------------- */

add_action('wp_head', 'wpse_43672_wp_head', 0);
/**
 * Hooks into the `wp_head` action.
 * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head
*/
function wpse_43672_wp_head(){ 
?> 

<script type='text/javascript'> 
(function(){ 
var bsa = document.createElement('script'); 
bsa.type = 'text/javascript'; 
bsa.async = true; 
bsa.src = '//cdn.beaconads.com/ac/beaconads.js'; 
(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]||document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(bsa); 
})(); 

</script> 

<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'Y 11111111', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//WWW.url.com/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>

<?php 
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `</head>` tags in the HTML.

Comment: Wow.. strange. I'm using a wordpress theme. Do you know where I would go to remove the /head that shouldn't be there?

Comment: You can remove it via `Admin panel->Apperance->Editor`. Look for the first `</head>` in the files on the right. I suggest starting with `Header.php`.

Comment: Thanks. I got that removed. It took care of some of the errors, but I still have some.

Comment: Move the `<div id="fb-root"></div>` outside of the `<head>` and into the `<body>`.

Comment: I'm using a "plugin" that hooks into my theme to add code to my body. I'll paste the code above. Someone created this for me. does it look incorrect?

Comment: The code seems fine its just doesn't need to go into the head. Simply copy the entire code from the first `<script type='text/javascript'>` to the last `</script>` and paste right after the `<body>` tag.

Comment: That's where I'm confused. So are you saying I need to actually edit my theme files? I thought that was what this plugin was supposed to do? That way I didn't have to go in and mess with theme files. No?

Comment: This plug in was made so my beacon ad code and google analyticas were hooked into the theme. Was the plug in done wrong? I'm confused.

Comment: By the way, I was following this post. Was what they said wrong? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43672/how-to-add-code-to-header-php-in-a-child-theme someone else also told me this was the best way to add this sort of code. No?

Comment: Update. I went in and manually added the code to my theme files, but now I'm getting lots of validation erros. I went from 14 to over 80?

Comment: Most of the code can go into the `head`. The only problem is with `<div id="fb-root"></div>` which cannot. The error count you saw before was false due to the extra `</head>` and the existence of a `div` inside the `head`. The current error count is correct and as you can see the Like Box is working.

Comment: I'm still getting 4 erors though. I don't know why I'm getting the admin error?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fnoahsdad.com%2F

Comment: The warnings are pretty clear. You are missing `fb:admins` and `fb:app_id` tags and you should remove the `fb:page_id` tag. read more here under `Open Graph Tags`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: Is the social graph totally separate than the code needed for these social apps (like the like box?) Also the like button (which is mentioned in that error) is put in by plug ins like jetpack. I didn't think id's were needed for the like buttons. Mine seems to be working the way it is. Can you help me understand how this works? Thanks.

Comment: The code needed for the like button and box is the base for these features to work. The social graph is used to enrich these plugins. Using the social graph will display more data on Facebook when someone likes your page. read here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind jumping in a chat so I can ask you a few more questions?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11487/discussion-between-yan-and-rick-smith)